# how to get dynamic date in django?

Tags: python, django

I've an Django site, where we have fields to get CurrentWeek and CurrentDate dynamically. 
**Issue:** Consider Apr 23, I started the server(using 
`python manage.py runserver`) then I'm getting the CurrentWeek and CurrentDate correctly. Further if I check that by tomorrow(Apr 24) as already the yesterday's(Apr 23) server command is still running, now it still taking the yesterday's(Apr 23) date as CurrentWeek and CurrentDate but not the today date(Apr 24).

I tried changing my Timezone to Asia/kolkata and my `settings.py` have
these:

```
USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

**emailinfo.py**

```
from datetime import date

weekNumber = date.today().isocalendar()[1]

currentweek = "week"+str(weekNumber)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from Taskmanager.email_info import currentweek

class Taskmanager(models.Model):
    CurrentSprint = models.CharField(max_length=10, 
                                     default=currentweek, 
                                     choices=week_number)
    todaydate = models.DateField()
```

**forms.py**

```
class Tasksadd(forms.ModelForm):
    todaydate = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget, 
                                initial=datetime.date.today())
    class Meta:
        model = Taskmanager
        fields = [
                  'CurrentSprint', 'todaydate',
                 ]
```

**task-create.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row ml-auto">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
                 <form method="POST" action=".">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                   </br>
                    <h3>Add tasks here:</h3>
                      {{ form|crispy }}
                         <input type="submit" name="submit" 
                             class="btn btn-info" 
                             placeholder="Submit">
                  </form>
               </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

I expect whenever I create a task, I need the CurrentWeek and CurrentDate fields need to fill dynamically the exact current date of the particular day. But, it takes the date of when I started server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `currentweek` should be a function, for example:

```
from datetime import date

def currentweek():
    weekNumber = date.today().isocalendar()[1]
    return "week{}".format(weekNumber)
```

in your case the `currentweek` is constant that calculated only one time when the server is start, so you haven't any problem on the develop because you start each day.

Comment: you've used return keyword for a constant is that correct or you missed something

Comment: sorry, that was a typo fixed.